# How can I vectorize the interaction of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider two numpy arrays:

1. array `a`:  The important feature of array `a` is that every pair of columns (`p` and `q`) has a row that holds values (`q` and `p`) in that order.
   For example,  columns 0 and 3  hold values 3 and 0 in row 2,   and columns 4 and 5 hold values 5 and 4 in row 1.

   ```py
   a = np.array([[1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 3],
                 [2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 4],
                 [3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2],
                 [4, 5, 3, 2, 0, 1],
                 [5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0]])
   ```
2. array `b`:  The first two columns show ALL column pairs (`p` and `q`) from array `a`. The remaining two columns are multipliers, as shown in the following:  Consider array `b`'s row 5  `[1, 2,  4, -3]`.   We examine columns 1 and 2 of array `a`, and locate the values 2 and 1.   Then we replace, in array `a`,  the 2 by 2x4=8, and we replace the 1 by 1x(-3) = -3.

   ```py
   b = np.array([[0, 1,  3  -1],
                 [0, 2, -1,  3],
                 [0, 3, -2,  4],
                 [0, 4, -1,  0],
                 [0, 5, -1,  4],
                 [1, 2,  4, -3],
                 [1, 3,  0, -1],
                 [1, 4,  1, -2],
                 [1, 5,  1,  1],
                 [2, 3,  1,  1],
                 [2, 4, -1,  0], 
                 [2, 5, -1,  1],
                 [3, 4,  0,  0],
                 [3, 5,  2,  1],
                 [4, 5,  1, -2]])
   ```

The final result would look like:

```py
   c = np.array([[ 3, 0,-4,10, 0, 3],
                 [-2, 0, 0,-1, 5,-8],
                 [-6, 4,-5, 0,-2, 2],
                 [-4, 5, 3, 2, 0, 1],
                 [-5, 8,-3, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Here is what I've been using.  It works well for smaller arrays (produces the array c shown above), but my coding skills are quite rusty:

```
c = np.copy(a)

for brow in b:       
    arow = np.where(a[:, brow[0]] == brow[1])
    c[arow, brow[0]] = (a[arow, brow[0]])*brow[2]
    c[arow, brow[1]] = (a[arow, brow[1]])*brow[3]  
    
print(c)
```

Could this be vectorized?

Comment: Often with questions like this, it is a good idea to post the looping code.  That clears up any ambiguities in the word description, and makes it easier to test any improvements.

Comment: How large are the matrices? It's always a question of whether it is even worth trying to vectorize the code if what you have works.

Comment: The largest array a would be 62x64, and this would make array b 4932x4.

Comment: @user109387 And at that size your current solution is too slow?

Comment: @user109387 Also, if you have 64 columns in `a`, then shouldn't `a` be of shape `(63,64)` and `b` be of shape `(2016, 4)`? From what you've shown, `a` should have one less row than columns while `b` should have 4 columns and the number of rows equal to the sum of numbers up to (and including) the number of columns in `a`.

Comment: @jared - yes, your dimensions are correct.   I’m trying to work from phone while travelling - my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which needs dimensionality ascension. Let's define your codes in a function for comparing the performance.

```
def find_c(a, b):
    c = np.copy(a)
    for brow in b:       
        arow = np.where(a[:, brow[0]] == brow[1])
        c[arow, brow[0]] = (a[arow, brow[0]])*brow[2]
        c[arow, brow[1]] = (a[arow, brow[1]])*brow[3] 
    return c
```

And my solution which I wrote some comments for explaining :

```
def find_c_1(a, b):
    c = np.copy(a)
    # ascension for indexing the data
    array_find = a[:, None][:, 0, b[:, 0]].T
    # find the index corresponds the values of b[:, 1] in array
    index = np.where(array_find == b[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1))
    
    # index[1] is the index of rows , b[:, 0] is the index of columns 
    # Then the assignment of the values
    c[index[1], b[:, 0]] = c[index[1], b[:, 0]] * b[:, 2]
    c[index[1], b[:, 1]] = c[index[1], b[:, 1]] * b[:, 3]
    return c
```

For comparing the result :

```
c1 = find_c(a, b)
c2 = find_c_1(a, b)
print(np.array_equal(c1, c2))  # True
```

For comparing the performance:

```
%timeit find_c(a, b)
314 µs ± 5.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit find_c_1(a, b)
23.8 µs ± 1.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```